# How do you check what version of Presto you are using?

Tags: presto

Postgres has:

```
SELECT VERSION();
```

**What is the Presto equivalent?**

I've taken a look through [Presto docs](https://prestodb.github.io/docs/current/index.html), but was not able to find an equivalent.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Have you tried the below?

```
SELECT node_version FROM system.runtime.nodes;
```

I tested on Presto 319 and Starburst Presto 312-e, but should work with pretty any Presto version.